# Why is my form_tag method a post when I am asking for a get?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

My form_tag looks like:

```
<%= form_tag(:controller => "users", :action => "confirm", :method => "get") %>
```

the html output is:

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/users/confirm?method=get" method="post">
```

Why is it doing this?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I think it's because when used in this form it assumes all of the options are url options.  Try.

```
<%= form_tag( '/users/confirm', :method => :get ) %>
```

In this case you have two separate sets of options, url options and tag options.

Comment: +1 Alternatively, be explicit with the hashes: `<%= form_tag({:controller => "users", :action => "confirm"}, :method => "get") %>`

Comment: This produces the same results for me sadly.

Answer (score 10):

The first 2 parameters of `form_tag` are `url_for_options` and `options`. Both are hash. So in your code, the whole hash is taken as `url_for_options`. So, to separate the parameters, you have to do like this:

```
<%= form_tag({:controller => "users", :action => "confirm"}, {:method => "get"}) %>
```

or

```
<%= form_tag({:controller => "users", :action => "confirm"}, :method => "get") %>
```

Refer [link](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-form_tag)