# In rails, when trying to submit a form_tag which is pointed at the index resource ("get"), I'm being pointed to a create path ("post")

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms, routes

Some details
- the form is on the page which it directs to (its supposed to just refresh the page, I've done this before successfully)
- I've tried these two

```
<%= form_tag yearly_derivatives_path(:method => "get") do %>
  <%= range_field_tag :liabilities_pctg_se_l, 50, :min => 0, :max => 100 %>
  <%= submit_tag %>
<% end %>
```

and

```
<%= form_tag(:method => "get") do %>
  <%= range_field_tag :liabilities_pctg_se_l, 50, :min => 0, :max => 100 %>
  <%= submit_tag %>
<% end %>
```

- this is the relevant routes.rb data

  `resources :yearly_derivatives`

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5320578/why-is-my-form-tag-method-a-post-when-i-am-asking-for-a-get

Answer (score 0):

Try,

`<%= form_tag yearly_derivatives_path, :method => "get" do %>`

Answer (score 0):

The default method used in form_tag is POST,
I think you are trying to pass :method => "get" to yearly_derivatives_path instead of form_tag,in this case form_tag continues using the default POST method.

This should work:

```
<%= form_tag :action => 'send_student_report_pdf', :method => 'get' %>
```