# Rails: Create action is fired even with "GET" method and "index" action specified

Tags: ruby-on-rails, filtering

My index view has a `form_tag` for filtering:

```
= form_tag action: "index", method: "get" do
  = label_tag(:sport_id, "Filter by sport:")
  = select_tag(:sport_id, options_from_collection_for_select(Sport.all, :id, :name))
  = submit_tag("Filter")
```

Teams controller:

```
def index
  @teams = Team.paginate(page: params[:page])
  # Note: this does not do any filtering yet.
end
```

When I submit the form, I get this error:

> ActionController::ParameterMissing in TeamsController#create
>
> param is missing or the value is empty: team

What I don't understand is why the `create` action is even firing in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first hash entries that are received by a form_tag are for the url_for_options hash

See this documentation http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-form_tag

```
form_tag(url_for_options = {}, options = {}, &block)
```

You need to make it clear that the `method` entry is part of the options hash instead

Try...

```
form_tag {action: "index"}, method: :get do
```

or...

```
form_tag '/teams', method: :get do
```

Comment: Thank you! Just found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5320578/why-is-my-form-tag-method-a-post-when-i-am-asking-for-a-get the same time you posted.