# Rails form going to create action instead of index action

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to create a search form that will take the result and push the param into the index of the Search controller. However, even though I specified the get method in the form I keep getting the error `The action 'create' could not be found for SearchController`, even though I'm trying to load the index.

home/index.html.erb

```
<%= form_tag(controller: "search", :url => search_index_path, :method 
=> :get) do %>
<%= label_tag(:name, "Search for:") %>
<%= text_field_tag(:name) %>
<%= submit_tag("Search") %>
<% end %>
```

search_controller.rb

```
class SearchController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @search = Tmdb::Search.tv(params[:name])
  end
  def show
  end
end
```

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
 root 'home#index'
 resources :home
 resources :search
end
```

Form Output:

```
<form action="/search?method=get" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post" abineguid="2F75F785E35A4ED5B614E26762C7B53B"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="✓"><input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="6dKa4a+vBvybu9b4eYwuEqx9dNcvadCyqRz7ox+ggW2YVAWq6Y8BWVNHx8nDWJbnQ4hTl5OTi3TSkjUfFuHbCQ==">
<label for="name">Search for:</label>
<input type="text" name="name" id="name">
<input type="submit" name="commit" value="Search" data-disable-with="Search">
</form>
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Inspect your output page in your web browser, and post the `<form>` tag that `form_tag` generates.

Comment: @Phlip I added the form output.

Comment: Possible answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5320578/why-is-my-form-tag-method-a-post-when-i-am-asking-for-a-get

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your call to form_tag is wrong.

**form_tag(url_for_options = {}, options = {}, &block)**

you are passing all options to url_for_options, including the :method.
You should do:

```
<%= form_tag({ controller: "search", action: "index" }, { :method 
=> :get }) do %>
```

Or simpler:

```
<%= form_tag(search_index_path, :method => :get) do %>
<%= label_tag(:name, "Search for:") %>
<%= text_field_tag(:name) %>
<%= submit_tag("Search") %>
<% end %>
```

See: https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/form_tag